# How to print a large number with exponential notation?

Tags: java, decimal, notation, exponential

If I have a number 52000000000, and I want to print it out as 5.2E+9, how do I do that with printf?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since it's a simple method I'll guide you through it.

You'll need two counters: one for the number itself (type double, let's call it 'num'), and one for the exponent (integer, let's call it exp). You'll need a while loop such that while num is greater than 10, divide num by 10 and increase exp by 1. So, something like 7600 should have num = 7.6, exp = 3.

Depending on your return type, you can return these values in numerous ways. A simple way would be to have return type string and return num+"E"+exp.

Comment: The base 10 exponent is the base 10 logarithm of the number, rounded down, `log(7600)=3.xx`. You dont need divisions in a loop.

Comment: Right... I haven't been able to think straight today. The asker should probably just mark your comment as an answer if that's possible. Much simpler and more efficient.

Comment: There was also a way to do this with printf("%e", number)

Answer (score 1):

This can be done with printf("%.2g", 52000000000);
"g" is the conversion character for scientific notation for formatting, and ".2" specifies the precision.

Answer (score 0):

You need to have a look at this : [DecimalFormat](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/text/DecimalFormat.html)

```
formatter = new DecimalFormat("0.#E0");
System.out.println(formatter.format(value));//value is where you store the number to be formatted
```

Comment: There doesn't seem to be a way to do this automatically with several different numbers of different lengths...

Comment: This is a better way of doing this, but this did seem like homework or some-such which is why I opted for the above.

Comment: I haven't been able to get this to work, but wouldn't that give me just two sig figs?